# Mobile Enterprise Application Platform (MEAP) recommendation?

Tags: java, android, iphone, c, mobile

I'm looking to receive some recommendations and opinions on the best Mobile Enterprise Application Platforms (MEAP) to be used to develop mobile applications for BlackBerry, iPhone, and Android.  The MEAP needs to support basic smartphone functionality (GPS, invoke calls, Maps [with route calculation], etc). Ideally, I'm looking to develop in Java. However, I would also consider C, C++, or Objective C. What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also handed the requirement of recommending and using a MEAP, more for the management of apps and devices, than the actual development of the apps.

There are a lot of players in the MEAP space, such as [Antenna](http://www.antennasoftware.com/),  [Sybase](http://www.sybase.com), [Pyxis Mobile](http://pyxismobile.com/), [Boxtone](http://www.boxtone.com/).  Antenna supports all features of all mobile platforms (!) with a java-like language and some if-iphone ... else if android ...   code.

There is a lot of discussion on [the enterprise mobility forum](http://theemf.org).   Here is a  [MEAP discussion.](http://theemf.org/groups/enterprise-mobility-management/forum/topic/meap-vendor-comparison/)

Imo, no body has quite gotten it solved for the general case, so they automate the easy 80% and then have ways to customize the remaining 20%- the platform differences. There are lots of tradeoffs: buy/build, ease of development vs native L+F, single provider vs. integrating tools yourself. So it depends greatly on your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create native apps, then the usual route is to use tools that have been created specifically for the platform by the platform owner. I.e. Xcode for iOS, Eclipse+Android SDK for Android, etc..

However, there are cross-platform development toolkits, but they are limited in scope http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_application_development

Comment: I'm very familiar with development in XCode and Eclipse, but unfortunately I am working on a project requiring use of a MEAP...

Comment: MEAP? Bullshit! I've been in Android since the beginning and never heard of it. Had to look it up: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_enterprise_application_platform
 It seems that there are only a handful vendors that fit the "definition"

Answer (score 0):

Antenna has recently announced full-java based development studio for developing applications on multiple devices (Android, iOS, Blackberry etc..). See press release [here](http://www.antennasoftware.com/news/press-releases/12-11-2012-antenna-enhances-ampchroma-platform-with-open-client-and-free-development-tools-).

Answer (score 0):

There are some new solutions introduced in MEAP such as  Dojo Toolkit, YUI Library, jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch which help to provide solution for hybrid mode.Pleas try them.

Hope these help.